# EmberJS: Test components html without rendering

Tags: javascript, ember.js

As far as I understand glimmer, embers new rendering engine, has a kind of virtual-dom implementation which is diffing for changes and updates the UI accordingly to those changes. To gain some speed in our tests I thought, it should be possible to use this this virtual dom to test a component without rendering it in the browser/phantomjs. In my normal integration tests I would do something like this:

```
it('shows a textarea', function(){
  this.render(hbs`{{my-component}}`); // don't render here
  const $textarea = this.$('textarea');
  expect($textarea).to.have.length(1);
});
```

So my question is if there is a way to access this virtual dom in a unit/integration test.

Thanks

Comment: Glimmer is internal code, and it looks nothing like DOM, it maintains a tree of rendering states, morphs and streams. I don't really see what gains you would expect from accessing that. I believe you may just be mistaken by the name `virtual dom`, which is more of a concept and technique than some concrete thing.

Comment: I was hoping to gain some speed on my integration tests, because if ember already "renders" my component (virtual dom) then I don't need to rerender it in the dom and afterwards query the dom with jquery.

Comment: This is where the term _virtual dom_ is misleading. Despite the name it is **not** a dom, and there is no rendering done. Glimmer just maintains a [tree of morphs and streams](https://cdn.auth0.com/blog/dombench/emberdom4.png), no dom at all. The whole point of this technique is precisely to avoid rendering.

Comment: Maybe I get this completely wrong, but when looking on the picture the stream tree has the exact same structure as the dom itself. So according to this picture it should be possible to get information about the actual dom from the stream tree (eg. is there an textearea node in this component) without rendering the stream tree to the dom.

Comment: You could extract partial information, but doing so would be 1) overly complex, 2) depend on the internal working of Glimmer, and 3) bear no resemblance whatsoever to dom. Here is what a render node looks like (copy pasted from debugger): https://gist.github.com/spectras/2331567aaaa36dbd8053. (elements are actual DOM elements, as that snapshot was taken from a fully rendered node)